# Path.GetFullPath doesn't return correct path

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, class, filepath

I was trying to use `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("Database.mdf")` in the class `DAL` in a website im creating but instead of returning :

`F:\MyProject\App_Data\Database.mdf`

It Returns `C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\Common Files\\\microsoftshared\\\DevServer\\\10.0\\\Database.mdf`

Anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/App_Data/Database.mdf")
```

Answer (score 6):

`Path.GetFullPath` return the full path of a file relative to the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` . In a web environment, consider using `HttpRequest.MapPath` .

Comment: HttpRequest.MapPath is excellent BUT I can only use in in aspx.cs pages (and it works there), but I wish to use it in a class. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @Or Betzalel, in another class use `HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath`.  But even this will only work when the current thread originated from an HTTP request.

Comment: string str = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("App_Data/suc.png"); Image imgCheckBoxChecked = Image.GetInstance(str);this is my code. I am working on WCF service and set image on pdf using itexsharp.But it gives me object refrence not set error. i dont know what is wrong with this code.